# What‘s the license for Google ML Kit? How should I obtain it?

Tags: google-mlkit, android-licenses

I want to use Google ML Kit in my Android app, but I can't find the relevant license. I'm not sure if I can use Google ML Kit for free in the commercial version of the app.

I found that the translation guidelines of Google ML Kit can only be used on mobile phones, tablets, laptops, and desktops（ https://developers.google.cn/ml-kit/language/translation?authuser=0#limitations ）I'm not sure if my VR glasses (Android System) app can be used